# Read file into binary byte array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, byte

Is there any way to read a file into a byte array and have it built with binary numbers only? For both binary files and "regular" files (.txt etc.)
(In Java)
I found a way to read a file into a byte array, but if the file is a binary file then the byte array contains negative numbers and i dont't know how to handle that as a binary number. I need my array to only contain 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are negative values, the bits are still correct.  The easiest thing you could do is wrap a `BitSet` around the `byte[]` so you can easily test individual bits:

```
 BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(myByteArray);

 boolean isBit20Set = bitSet.get(20);
```